# Google sheet - weekly minimum count

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a google spreadsheet list, with two columns (200+rows and counting), that looks like this:

```
Monday    495,636,792
Tuesday 891,243,349
Wednesday   465,844,622
Thursday    425,461,946
Friday  412,401,861
Saturday    424,297,897
Sunday  462,782,430
Monday  454,216,725
Tuesday 1,661,014,800
Wednesday   502,935,706
Thursday    493,009,684
Friday  464,568,911
Saturday    670,963,371
Sunday  491,847,275
```

(I also have a regular date column, not just the weekdays - if needed)

I would like to count the weekly minimum.
This basically means that I would like an other list that would look like this:

```
Monday  10
Tuesday 15
Wednesday 20
Thursday    0
Friday  9
Saturday    7
Sunday  25
```

**Monday - 10** would mean, that there were 10 weeks, where Monday had the smallest number during that week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I did not understand correctly. This is mot as hard. See corrected code below. The sample sheet is also corrected.

```
function minDays() {
  var s= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var clr = s.getRange(2,2,7,1).clear()
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()-1
  var slr = 7
  var sr = 2
  var weeks = lr/7
  for(w=1;w<weeks+1;w++){
  if(w==1){sr=sr,slr==slr} else {sr=sr+7,slr=slr+7}
     var sVal = ss.getRange(sr,1,slr,2).getValues();
     var minVal =sVal[1][1]
     var minDay =sVal[0][0]
    for (var i = 1; i < 7;i++) { 
      if(sVal[i-1][1]<=minVal){minVal=sVal[i-1][1],minDay=sVal[i-1][0]} else{minVal=minVal,minDay=minDay}
        var fVal=minVal
        var fday = minDay
    }
  var target=s.getRange(2,1,7,2).getValues();
  for(var n in target){
    var row = target[n][0]
   if(row.toString().match(fday)){
    var cnt = target[n][1].valueOf()+1
    target[n][1]=cnt
    }}
  var rDay =s.getRange(2, 1,7,2)
  var data=rDay.getValues()
  rDay.setValues(target)
}}

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFHeNKeonLDuuOyg7GaTvMB4asvnYHbK2C0WAEbfSsI/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. That is not a set of 3 numbers, but a big number. So 891,243,349 is actually 891243349. I am (still) looking for the smallest number in the week.

Comment: Try it now. Sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: I am hospitalized. I promise I will get back to you on this later